# Exporting data from Microsoft Access table file subsets to plain text

Tags: ms-access, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

I have a problem in exporting data from Microsoft Access. I have an Access file made of several rows and columns, like this:

[image: Data table main data]

Every row contains a subset of data, that could be observed by clicking on the "+" button:

[image: Data table subsets]

I would like to export all these data (main table & subsets), but there's a problem.
When I click on External Data -> Export -> Text file, Ms Access exports only the main table data (1st Figure), and completely omits the data of the subsets (2nd Figure).

**How could I export all these data (main table & subsets)?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a query denormalizing the data you want the way you want, then export that to Excel.